# openmp 4.0 accelerator support

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to find a solution to offload the cpu code to Nvidia GPU using openmp 4.0 but there isnt any significant improvement in the execution time of the code that what it is while running using normal openmp directives.

I am using #pragma omp target directive and then parallelizing the code using normal #pragma omp parallel for but there is no improvement in the execution time by using #pragma omp target directive.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your tool chain actually supports these new directives? Just for example, gcc only started to support offloading as of gcc 5.0.

Comment: I agree with @JerryCoffin.  Furthermore, there are a million-and-one reasons why simply shifting a computation from CPU to GPU wouldn't increase the execution speed.  So even if your toolchain does support the new directives, even if you are correctly offloading the work, there's no real help anyone can offer without a lot more detail.  Some code would help too.

Comment: @JerryCoffin..Yes I am not very sure that the compiler supports these directives, what I have learnt that gcc version 4.9 and above supports openmp 4.0 hence I am assuming these directives would work, also is there a way to come to know as to whether these directives are working or not?